# SQLite How to Combine the Check Constraints with Select Subquery on another table

Tags: sqlite, select

As it said, I want to add a constraint to a table, and find cannot make Check and Select together.

Here is What I did:

```
Alter Table table2 Add Constraint chk_table2 Check(Colume21 IN (Select Colume11 From Table 1));
```

Why does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#ckconst) says:

> The expression of a CHECK constraint may not contain a subquery.

In any case, you cannot use [ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) to add a constraint later.

However, your constraint looks like a [foreign key](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), which *is* supported.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly answer to my question.